# Django regex not working when adding other branches to url

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am a complete beginner in Django, and I have encountered a problem while trying to set up a url for each "room".
Here is the code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^room/<str:pk>/$', views.room, name='room'),

]
```

Everything was working perfectly, until I add `/<str:pk>/$`. I have also add this code in the views.py section:

```
def room(request,pk):
    return render(request, 'base/room.html')
```

However I still get an error when loading the website.
[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL1pa.png)

Does someone know how to make it work?

Comment: you have to add a pk in your url something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/1/` i think you notice that `1` is just here the pk.you are getting an errror because you did not provide a `pk` in your url.

Comment: No sadly, this also doesn't work. It shows me the same error page than in the image, telling that "the current path, room/1/, didn't match" any of the urlpatterns.

Comment: Hello @Flusten in error image you're on ``room/`` not on `room/<id>/` that's why it's giving you 404

Comment: Hey, I completely understand what you mean, however even if enter in the URL `room/1/` or any other id that I had setup it still sends me the same 404 error ( just with the url name changed ). Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstfully, as said in comments, you have to put `pk` in url and follow that:

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/1/
   ```
2. Then, make sure you have at least one `Room` object in database, otherwise the url will not be active.
3. Last thing, it should be rather `<int:pk>` than `str`, because I believe your `pk` is a classic `id` as a number. So urls:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(r'^room/<int:pk>/$', views.room, name='room'),

   ]
   ```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your reply put even when I have this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/1/` the same error shows up. I have 3 dictionnaries in my "rooms" list build like the following `{'id':1,'name':"Lets learn python !"},`. I completely agree with you on rather putting `<int:pk>` but sadly this doesn't solve the problem. Would you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: And you have exactly same error? Could you show it?

Comment: Thanks to your comment on rather using `<int:pk>`, I got interested in the different methods there is on this subject. Found something that works ! Used this instead and worked out perfectly : `url(r'^room/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.room, name='room'),`

Comment: Well, yeah. you should use newer version of Django and `path` instead of `url`. It's depreciated and you may have more errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced `/<str:pk>/$` by `/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.room, name='room'),` and worked out perfectly !